# How to draw a circle through two points (at diameter end)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

There are two points on the stereographic projection as shown in the figure:

[image]

These points are supposed to be on the end points of a dimeter of a circle. How to draw a circle passing through these two points?

Code for the above plot:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splev, splrep

# create instance of basemap, note we want a south polar projection to 90 = E
myMap = Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=0,lon_0=180,resolution='l',round=True,suppress_ticks=True)
# set the grid up
gridX, gridY = 10.0, 15.0
parallelGrid = np.arange(-90.0,90.0,gridX)
meridianGrid = np.arange(-180.0,180.0,gridY)

# draw parallel and meridian grid, not labels are off. We have to manually create these.
myMap.drawparallels(parallelGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False])
myMap.drawmeridians(meridianGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False],labelstyle='+/-',fmt='%i')


# plot azimuth labels, with a North label.
ax = plt.gca()
ax.text(0.5,1.025,'N',transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='bottom',size=25)
for para in np.arange(gridY,360,gridY):
    x= (1.1*0.5*np.sin(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    y= (1.1*0.5*np.cos(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    ax.text(x,y,u'%i\N{DEGREE SIGN}'%para,transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')

summerAzi = np.array([0, 360])
summerAlt = np.array([40, 4])
summerX, summerY = myMap(summerAzi, -summerAlt)


summerX_new = np.linspace(summerX.min(), summerX.max(),30)
summerY_smooth = splev(summerX_new, splrep(summerX, summerY, k=1))

myMap.plot(summerX_new, summerY_smooth, 'g')

myMap.plot(summerX, summerY, 'go')   
plt.show()
```

Comment: Two points can define infinitely many circles, and are you talking about circles in the projection space (as we see) or circles in the mathematical space (the data that's being represented)

Comment: @NickT; Yes, you are right. I updated the question. These points are the end points of a diameter of the circle.

Comment: Because of the projection, does it not work to calculate midpoint of line and use `circ=plt.Circle((myX,myY), radius=myRad)`

Comment: @beroe; No it won't work, but if you have any though then you can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inbuilt tissot() function is good enough to plot circles on a conformal projections (as in this case). On non-conformal projections, it plots ellipses.
Here the mid point of the tissot indicatrix is (0, -22) in degrees.
Its radius = (40-4)/2 = 18 in degrees.
Number of points = 36 is fine.

The relevant code is:

```
myMap.tissot(0, -22, 18, 36, \
             facecolor='none', \
             edgecolor='#ff0000', \
             linewidth=1, \
             alpha=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The circle in this polar representation will not look like a circle on a rectangular grid (i.e. "round"). Apart from that you can draw a circle just as you would on the cartesian plane, starting in polar coordinates, transforming to cartesian coordinates, offset the center and use the plot function.

```
summerAzi = np.array([0, 360])
summerAlt = -np.array([40, 4])
summerX, summerY = myMap(summerAzi, summerAlt)

phi = np.linspace(0,2.*np.pi)
r = np.abs(np.diff(summerAlt))/2.
x = r*np.cos(phi)
y = -r*np.sin(phi)+summerAlt.mean()
X,Y= myMap(x,y)

myMap.plot(X,Y, color="crimson")
myMap.plot(summerX, summerY, color="gold", marker="o")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way a circle can be plotted and then can be placed on top of this polar representation? The actual situation is something different different. Data set is like `summerAzi = np.array([180, 360])`.

Comment: Sorry, without clear problem description I cannot do anything to help you.

Comment: Can't we do something like this: `#%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
circle = plt.Circle((0, .3), 0.6, transform=ax.transData._b, color="red", alpha=0.1)
ax.add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
` using `summerAzi` and `summerAlt` in the question?

Comment: I tried to draw circle with this [code](https://repl.it/GbiR/13) with no luck. Could please see if any chance adjusting centre of the circle may give some result?